Поставил Ubuntu и скорость при скачке в Steam как будто урезана
давно не ставил Ubuntu поставил его и тут я встретился с проблемой при скачке в Steam скорость маленькая для меня это не плохо но хотелось бы знать в чем проблема вообще
wlx2887bae2774b  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"RT-5GPON-A587"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.18 GHz  Access Point: F4:E5:78:C8:A5:8C   
          Bit Rate=390 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=50/70  Signal level=-60 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:3985   Missed beacon:0

драйвера поставил на данный свисток, название свистка TP-Link Archer T4U v3

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Тут: http://steamcommunity.com/app/221410/discussions/2/616189106498372437/?l=russian
И тут: https://github.com/ValveSoftware/steam-for-linux/issues/3401
Все хорошо описано. Кратко: это не баг клиента, просто win кеширует dns, linux нет.
Решение: ставим себе любой кэширующий dns.
sudo aptitude install dnsmasq
В resolv.conf Первой строкой добавляем: nameserver 127.0.0.1
cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 192.168.1.2
Перезапускаем dnsmasq
sudo service dnsmasq restart
P.S. все те, у кого в ликсе со скоростью все норм => испльзуют ротер у которого на борту настроен dns cashe
(ответ пусть и не мой но написан хорошо(https://www.linux.org.ru/forum/games/10947292))
